# Where can I get Little Generals source code?

Tags: ios, scorched-earth

Little Generals was a - now discontinued - version of Scorched Earth for iPhone and Android.

It was a great version and I miss it.

Does anyone know where I can find the developer and source code?

Thanks!

Comment: What makes you think the source code is publicly available?

Comment: Nothing makes me believe it is public - on the contrary

Answer (score 3):

You can't get the source code, if it isn't publicly available. There are such things as decompilers, but you really just can't do it unless the devs wanted you to get the code.

Comment: Decompilers also only work if the code is in a certain language, such as C#. There is a high change that it is in C/C++ which cannot be decompiled. (Idk what language this game is in)

Comment: Yeah, I know. That's why I made sure to say it probably wouldn't work, or be worth it.

Comment: yep I assumed you did! That comment was more meant for other users and the asker reading this

Answer (score -6):

You can get the source code from the developer of the app, @smarterapps on twitter.
Maybe send them a message with an offer for how much you think it's worth, but the details of the offer or how you ask them to give you a copy of the source code are up to you.

Comment: "*You can get the source code from the developer*" Is that a guarantee? What if the developer already sold their source code, and is no longer legally permitted to sell it to anyone else?

Comment: Or to add onto what Nolonar said, what if he doesn't **want to** or **care.** I don't see this working; if it's not public already i doubt he'd give it to you